# What are the math processes to get from $1-a$ to $1 - \frac{.1a}{1-.9a}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the math processes to get the following equation?
$$\begin{align}
&\;1 - a \\[4pt]
=&\; 1 -.9a-.1a \\[4pt]
=&\; 1 - \frac{.1a}{1-.9a}
\end{align}$$
I understand the second line, splitting the $a$ into $.9a$ and $.1a$. I just have no idea how they managed to get the final form.

Comment: They are not the same. The final expression is $(1-a)/(1-0.9a)$. You can see that the initial and final expressions are unequal for, let's say, $a=0.5$.

Comment: That is false. Perhaps you mean $1-\frac{.1 a}{1-.9}$.

Comment: As for general tips to change how expressions look, you can always multiply things by $1$ or add $0$ and not change the value of the expression.  The trick is what "$1$" and "$0$" looks like at the time.  For instance $\frac{x}{x+2}=\frac{x+\color{red}{0}}{x+2}=\frac{x+\color{red}{2-2}}{x+2}=\frac{x+2}{x+2}-\frac{2}{x+2}=1-\frac{2}{x+2}$

Comment: There are no "math processes", here.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the case $a=0$ holds. Since
$$1-a=1-\frac{0.1a}{1-0.9a} \Rightarrow 1=\frac{0.1}{1-0.9a} \Rightarrow 1-0.9a=0.1a \Rightarrow 1=a,$$
your equations hold iff $a \in \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1-0.9a-0.1a$$
$$=\frac{1-0.9a-0.1a}{1-0.9a}\times(1-0.9a)$$
$$=\biggl(\frac{1-0.9a}{1-0.9a}-\frac{0.1a}{1-0.9a}\biggr)\times(1-0.9a)$$
$$=\biggl(1-\frac{0.1a}{1-0.9a}\biggr)\times(1-0.9a)$$

But the final form in your post lacks the term $(1-0.9a)$ multiplied to it. So, your final form is either wrong
$$(OR)$$

Otherwise, it is true for certain values of $a$. So we need to solve for $a$ in your equation.
$$1-a=1-\frac{0.1a}{1-0.9a}$$
$$-a=-\frac{0.1a}{1-0.9a}$$
$$0=a-\frac{0.1a}{1-0.9a}$$
$$\Rightarrow a-0.9a^2-0.1a=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 0.9a-0.9a^2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow 0.9a(1-a)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow a=1,a=0$$

So, the final form holds good if $a=0$ or $a=1$. It is wrong For other values of $a$.